# JS Boilerplate for Server has client.tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, boilerplate

I need to get into Web development and am currently looking at Node.js using React and Redux. As I come from a .NET Background, I'd like to have TypeScript, so my choice for a boilerplate was limited. I found this one:
https://github.com/barbar/vortigern

This boilerplate has got a client.tsx and a server.tsx. I don't understand what the point of the client is. I mean, this is meant for developing a frontend, right? There is only need for a server, what's the purpose of the client? I just can't find out. In the webpack config, there are two files for the server and the client, but I couldn't find out when which one is called.

I hope someone can explain the purpose of this client to me! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you're new to web development, I suggest sticking with a client side only setup (which is by far the most common). Because it's possible to render React components on the server there are also "isomorphic" setups that are both client and server side, but that's a much more complicated setup especially for someone just starting out. Here's a boilerplate that might suit you better https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-typescript-boilerplate

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at that boilerplate then. But just to understand, I'd still like to know why there are two js files needed. I thought server side rendering was also done in the main server file (server.tsx) which then sends the rendered HTML to the client (for me, the client is the WebBrowser looking at the page). So what I still wonder is, why is there a client.tsx on my server implementation? (For me, the whole project and folder structure is a 'server') I don't know, even with server side rendering, what the purpose of the server side client file is...

Comment: Forgot to mention you, @azium

Answer (score 0):

Vortigern is an isomorphic react typescript template. That means you write the code once and the same code runs on the client and server. Client and server side code have different configuration (for example, there is no express/http server on client side), so there are two entry points which load the necessary resources for client and server respectively:

- client.tsx file is the entry point for your client-side code
- server.tsx file is the entry point for server side